# Rewriting SQL statement into PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to rewrite a SQL statement in PL/SQL but I am new to this and I can't get it right.

This is the original statement:

```
select f.flugnummer, p.nachname, pl.sitzplatznummer, l.bezeichnung, r.reisepassnr, 
sum(g.gewicht) as Luggage
from passagierliste pl join flug f on f.flugID = pl.flugID
join gepaeck g on pl.personID = g.personID
join person p on pl.personID = p.personID
join reisepass r on p.personID = r.personID
join land l on r.landID = l.landID
where f.flugnummer ='AF3012'and pl.sitzplatznummer = '13'
group by f.flugnummer, p.nachname, pl.sitzplatznummer, l.bezeichnung, r.reisepassnr;
```

And this is my attempt in PL/SQL where I am trying to return a passenger who is on the flight AF3012 and seat 13:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getPassenger IS
v_flugnummer varchar2(30);
v_sitzplatz varchar2(30);
BEGIN
v_flugnummer := 'AF3012';
v_sitzplatz := '13';
select f.flugnummer, p.nachname into v_nachname, pl.sitzplatznummer, l.bezeichnung, r.reisepassnr into v_reisepassnr, 
sum(g.gewicht) as Luggage into v_luggage
from passagierliste pl join flug f on f.flugID = pl.flugID
join gepaeck g on pl.personID = g.personID
join person p on pl.personID = p.personID
join reisepass r on p.personID = r.personID
join land l on r.landID = l.landID
where f.flugnummer =v_flugnummer and pl.sitzplatznummer = v_sitzplatz
group by f.flugnummer, p.nachname, pl.sitzplatznummer, l.bezeichnung, r.reisepassnr;

IF v_sitzplatz > 0 THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_nachname || ' ' || v_flugnummer || ' ' || v_sitzplatz || ' ' || v_reisepassnr || ' ' || v_luggage);
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '0');
END IF;
COMMIT;
END;
/
exec getPassenger;
```

Comment: Just adding the error message. I also believe there is a problem with the group by function.Thank you.  => Warning: execution completed with warning

Errors for PROCEDURE GETPASSENGER
---------------------------------
L:7 C:1         PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
L:7 C:99        PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit simplified (as I removed unnecessary columns your `SELECT` returned), this is what might work.

- don't hardcode parameters; pass them into the procedure for more flexibility
- every column `select` returns has to have its own variable to put that value into. You can't select e.g. 10 columns into e.g. 2 variables; that just won't work
- if query doesn't return anything, it'll raise `NO_DATA_FOUND` you should handle

---

```
create or replace procedure getpassenger (par_flugnummer in varchar2,
                                          par_sitzplatz  in varchar2
                                         )
is
  v_nachname person.nachname%type;
begin
  -- find the passenger
  select p.nachname 
  into v_nachname
  from passagierliste pl join flug f on f.flugid = pl.flugid
  join gepaeck g on pl.personid = g.personid
  join person p on pl.personid = p.personid
  join reisepass r on p.personid = r.personid
  join land l on r.landid = l.landid
  where f.flugnummer = par_flugnummer 
    and pl.sitzplatznummer = par_sitzplatz;

  -- passenger has been found - display it
  dbms_output.put_line(v_nachname || ' ' || par_flugnummer || ' ' || par_sitzplatz);

exception
  when no_data_found then
    -- passenger hasn't been found so previous SELECT returned
    -- NO_DATA_FOUND; handle it
    dbms_output.put_line('Nobody sits there');
end;
/
exec getpassenger(par_flugnummer => 'AF3012', par_sitzplatz => '13');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can create the procedure without any errors now, however when executing it I receive the following message: An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETPASSENGER'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored [SQL State=65000, DB Errorcode=6550]

Comment: You're welcome. Error says that you didn't pass expected number of parameters. It expects 2, I don't know what you passed. See the last line in my code; that's how you should have done it.

Comment: I executed the last line from your code. Which is passing 2 parameters, type of varchar2.  I don't see why it doesn't work now...

Comment: Ah, typos. Not flugnum**b**er but flugnummer; not sitzplatz**t** but sitzplatz. Fixed now (the last line in my example). Try that.